# Encuentro local de SOes en Bogotá, Colombia - 23 de mayo del 2018

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

**Fecha:** 23 de Mayo de las 6:30pm - 8:30pm

**Dirección:** [Vivelab en la Carrera 45 #26-33](https://www.google.com/maps?q=Carrera+45+%2326-33&entry=gmail&source=g), en las instalaciones de RTVC, en Bogotá.

Invitamos a todos los interesados en la informática y en en el desarrollo a participar en un encuentro informal para conocernos más y aprender sobre la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español.  Tenemos espacio para un pequeño grupo de 25 solamente.

Tendremos aperitivos y bebidas para los invitados y daremos una presentación sobre la comunidad de desarrolladores de Stack Overflow en español.  Daremos tiempo también para networking y para convivio con los asistentes.

¡Nos vemos muy pronto! Aparten su lugar al seguir el enlace en la respuesta.  Así podremos saber quienes van a venir.

Comment: ¿Se tiene previsto un encuentro local en alguna ciudad de España?. Gracias.

Comment: @wchiquito mándame un email ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para registrase, síganle aquí: [Meetup en Bogotá](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/stack-overflow-en-espanol-meetup-en-bogota-tickets-45743955402)

Comment: ¿Hay fotos del evento?